# SQL Management Studio - End of line selection for multiple lines

Tags: select, notepad++, ssms, multiline

I have been Googling this for sometime and used the question search functionality here before posting.

In SSMS I want to edit the end of each line in the same way ALT + Shift can be used to edit the start of every line.

Notepad++ can achieve this using the replace functionality with a regex condition by specifying $ - end of line. However this seems unreliable and a little buggy.

Ideally I want to achieve this in SSMS I would like one editor that is great for MS SQL and helps my coding productivity.
I have looked into sublime but interfacing with the DB securely or reliably looks problematic.

Anything that avoids be going to the end of 700 lines of code and manually entering the same info would be great.

I am also looking into creating macros with AutoHotkey to improve coding performance.

Comment: In SQL Management Studio I found I can carry out a replace and use the reg expression using these params: ".$"

. = Matches any single character except a line break.
$ = Anchors the match string to the end of a line.

This still is'nt ideal as there is no shortcut key but I suppose it works.

Answer (score 2):

In SQL Management Studio I found I can carry out a replace and use the reg expression using these params: ".$" . = Matches any single character except a line break. $ = Anchors the match string to the end of a line. This still is'nt ideal as there is no shortcut key but I suppose it works.